# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image type not supported coming for JPEG Images in PDFBox, How to fix this?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to add Header and footer in every page in pdf. I have base64 img of the header and footer. When I try to add them in pdf JPEG type images are giving error. PNG images are working fine

```
public byte[] getPdf(PrintTemplate pt) throws ApplicationException {
        byte[] reportByte = null;
        String headerLogo = getBase64Image(pt.getImg1pathEx());
        String footerLogo = getBase64Image(pt.getImg3pathEx());
        try {
            String inputFilePath = "input.pdf"; 
            String outputFilePath = "output.pdf";

            File file = new File(inputFilePath);
            
            try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < doc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                    
                    PDPage page = doc.getPage(i);
                    
                    
                    try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
                        if(pt.getExternal_file_header_add() !=null && pt.getExternal_file_header_add()){
                           if(headerLogo !=null && !"".equals(headerLogo)){
                              PDImageXObject headerImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(headerLogo, doc);
                              contents.drawImage(headerImage,pt.getHeader_x_positionEx() , pt.getHeader_y_positionEx());  //header
                           }
                        }
                        if(pt.getExternal_file_footer_add() !=null && pt.getExternal_file_footer_add()){
                            if(footerLogo !=null && !"".equals(footerLogo)){
                               PDImageXObject footerImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(footerLogo, doc);
                                contents.drawImage(footerImage, pt.getFooter_x_positionEx(), pt.getFooter_y_positionEx());  //footer
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                doc.save(outputFilePath);
            }

            reportByte = convertDocToByteArray(outputFilePath);

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return reportByte;
    }
```

Comment: You say those images are base encoded. Have you tried base64-decoding them before feeding them to PDFBox?

Comment: Are `headerLogo` and `footerLogo` paths of files containing *base64 img*? Or are they already the base64 encoded images themselves?

Comment: @mkl pt.getImg1pathEx()-> It will give me the image url. using that image url i'm creating base64 Image

Comment: Please post a stack trace and complete error message

Comment: @Ganesh *" pt.getImg1pathEx()-> It will give me the image url. using that image url i'm creating base64 Image"* - so `getBase64Image` returns a String containing the base64 encoded image? Then the issue is clear, the first String argument of `PDImageXObject.createFromFile` is expected to be a file path, not an image. Also, is there a reason why you base64 encode the images? PDFBox expects unencoded images...